# error: conversion from string to date is not valid

Tags: .net

i just want to save date by using date time picker in vb.net. but i am getting error: "conversion from string to date is not valid"here is my code:

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(Dal.conMain)
        'Dim trns As sqltransaction
        Dim obj As New clsProductMaster()
        **obj.invoicedate = dtpdate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")**
        obj.consignor_id = ddlConsignor.SelectedItem.ToString()
        obj.demurrage_days = txtdemurragedays.Text
        obj.demurrage_rate = txtdemmuragerate.Text
```

type of invoicedate is datetime. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `invoicedate` is a `DateTime` property, why do you convert the already available `DateTime` to string before you assign it?

So instead of

```
obj.invoicedate = dtpdate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

just

```
obj.invoicedate = dtpdate.Value.Date
```

i assume that you just want the date portion without time so i've used [`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @PriyankaNautiyal: but the error must be somewhere else since the line `obj.invoicedate = dtpdate.Value.Date` cannot cause it since you've mentioned that `invoicedate` is a `DateTime`. Is that really a `DateTime` property or do you just refer to your database column?

Comment: i just refer to database column.

Comment: you were right the error was somewhere else. thanku so much  :)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that `obj.invoicedate` is already a `DateTime` therefore you can make a straight assignment

```
obj.invoicedate = dtpdate.Value
```

Comment: @PriyankaNautiyal. Are you still getting the same error? Or did the error change?